# Automatically push engine datastore data to bigquery tables

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

To move data from datastore to bigquery tables I currently follow a manual and time consuming process, that is, backing up to google cloud storage and restoring to bigquery. There is scant documentation on the restoring part so this post is handy http://sookocheff.com/posts/2014-08-04-restoring-an-app-engine-backup/

Now, there is a seemingly outdated article (with code) to do it https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery

I've been, however, waiting for access to this experimental tester program that seems to automate the process, but gotten no access for months https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1HpC2B1HmtYv_PuHPsUGz_Odq0Nb43_6ySfaVJufEJTc/viewform?formkey=dHdpeXlmRlZCNWlYSE9BcE5jc2NYOUE6MQ

For some entities, I'd like to push the data to big query as it comes (inserts and possibly updates). For more like biz intelligence type of analysis, a daily push is fine.

So, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways of entering data into bigquery:

- through the UI
- through the command line
- via API

If you choose API, then you can have two different ways: "batch" mode or streaming API.

If you want to send data "as it comes" then you need to use the streaming API. Every time you detect a change on your datastore (or maybe once every few minutes, depending on your needs), you have to call the [insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll) method of the API. Please notice you need to have a table created beforehand with the structure of your datastore. (This can be done via API if needed too).

For your second requirement, ingesting data once a day, you have the full code in the [link you provided](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery). All you need to do is adjust the JSON schema to those of your data store and you should be good to do.